# Ubuntu 20.004 lts, /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsk at each boot

Tags: boot, dpkg, initramfs, fsck

i got an error after that my nephew disconnected my pc, when booting a message appears saying that `the root filesystem /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsk`
I did a `fsck -y /dev/sda5` and all back to normal but when i shut down my pc and restart it another day the same error appears and sometimes i have to boot on the recovery mode(ubuntu 05, accessible in the grub) and do a `dpkg` to access my pc desktop.

What can be the problem ? Why should i have to solve this error a each boot ? (even if sometimes the error doesn't occurs)

Please i'm waiting for your help :[

Comment: II have an intel core i5, 4gb ram...if it can help //

Comment: Please...i need help